# Trying to get a localhost copy working

Tags: migrations

I've transferred all of the files for a Drupal build to my localhost, imported the database into my local WAMP server, however when I try to access the drupal build on my localhost, it keeps giving me an error, saying it cannot connect (connection reset). Other sites on localhost work fine.

What would cause this?

The connection details are the following ones:

```
array('database' => 'default_drupal',
  'username' => 'default_drupal',
  'password' => '1r3s3tM3',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'prefix' => '',
);
```

I created an account using the account default_drupal on the default_drupal database, so it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me it was due to the ["Coder"](http://drupal.org/node/1277726) module. It was caused by a multi-line description in the coder_upgrade.info file (I don't know why that was a problem). So if you have installed that module, then open coder_upgrade.info and change the description to fit in one line.

If that's not your problem then try these following steps:

1. Move each module outside the modules folder and reload the webpage
   each time you do this. If the problem is caused by a module then you
   can make modifications as necessary.
2. Try upgrading or reinstalling your **WAMP** server.
3. If you had enabled **caching** in your production server, then follow [this link](http://ghita.org/drupal-the-connection-was-reset.html).(**Note** : The article is for Drupal-6. You can find the code for drupal-7 in their comments section)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any Drupal performance optimizations on the site that's the source of your imported database? [This article](http://ghita.org/drupal-the-connection-was-reset.html) suggests turning them off and gives a query to accomplish that.

Once you've got your local site up and running, I also suggest trying the [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module to manage your data migration. You can create a backup profile that omits your live server's cache data, which makes for a smaller backup file and may mitigate the problem you're having now.